# UITableView is not setting height as specified

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView and I have set height of tableview to 308. For each cell, they are of size 154 as shown in screenshots.

[image]

Now when I run this and I have 3 rows in UITableView. I was expecting to remain height as 308 only and expecting to have scrolling option. On scrolling I will see row 3 also, however UITableView is behaving differently. It is taking whole screen as shown below.

[image]

If you see, I can see third row and height of the row is increased.

To adjust height if tableview, I added below code in viewWillAppear,

```
mainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(mainTableView.frame.origin.x, mainTableView.frame.origin.y, 320, 308);
```

When I run this first time, I see all three rows. WHen I try to add and comes back to Home screen, I now see two rows only. But the problem is when I scroll, it crashes.

Crash says

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
```

But this is not actual problem. If this is problem, then it should have also been crashed when I go to HomeViewController for the first time.

Any suggestion how should I solve this UITableView problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your springs and struts are configured to autoresize the `UITableView` to fit the screen height and width. If you only need to table view to be 308px in height disable the vertical arrow in the "View" section of the interface builder when the table view is selected. Also as far as your problem goes it looks like you don't have the `clipsToBounds` property enabled for the table view.

Comment: The "springs and struts" as you term them will not "autoresize the UITableView to fit the screen height and width". They should keep the tableview at a fixed distance from the top/bottom/left/right of the containing view and alter the width/height of the table view to make this true.

Comment: Thanks Bro... its worked... Great great great... Will accept answer after 2 mins...